# Merge many CSV files

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I have set of 500 csv files. Each file has four columns and variable number of rows.

I want to merge all of these csv's into one common sheet. If someone can help me in doing this in PowerShell, it would be great.

```
Sample Data in Excel 1:

Name  Age  Marks  Class
A      15   100    5
B      20   88     6

Sample Data in Excel 2:
Name   Age  Marks  Class
C      11   99      2

Output :
Name   Age   Marks   Class
A      15    100      5
B      20     88      6
C      11     99      2
```

Comment: Are you married to powershell for this task, or can you use Excel?

Comment: You mention CSVs at one point but you call them excel sheets. Are they all CSVs? Or are they actually Excel sheets?

Comment: All are CSV's. Sorry for that.

Comment: Though excel is also fine ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the CSV files are in one folder then:

```
$res = @()
ls *.csv | %{
  $temp = Import-CSV $_
  $res += $temp
}
$res | Export-CSV .\ALLINFO.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The break down:

- `$res = @()` - Make an array called $res that will hold all the data. This isn't strictly required. You could do it in a way that appends to a result file directly.
- `ls *.csv |` - Find all the CSV files in the folder and pass them to the next command.
- `%{$temp = Import-CSV $_; $res += $temp}` - Take each of those files, import the CSV data into a holder variable called `$temp`. Add the contents of `$temp` to the collector variable `$res`. Again it is not necessary to use the intermediate `$tamp` variable, I just find it more clear to do so.
- `$res | Export-CSV .\ALLINFO.csv -NoTypeInformation` - Now that the data from all the files is in `$res`, export `$res` to a new file.

Answer (score 4):

If the files are large then you could merge them as text documents. This is a lot faster than importing csv-objects, but it requires that the properties and the order in which they're placed are equal in all files. Example:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "*.csv"
#Get header
$text = @(Get-Content -Path $files[0].FullName -TotalCount 1)

$files | ForEach-Object {
    #Get text but skip header
    $text += Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1
}

#Save merged csv
$text | Set-Content Output.csv
```

Output.csv

```
Name;Age;Marks;Class
A;15;100;5
B;20;88;6
C;11;99;2
```

You could optimize it even more by replacing `Get-Content` for `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines()` etc. but I skipped that now as it's more complicated/hard to read.

**UPDATE:** Added alternative solution that saves the output-file part for part as Ansgar suggested.

```
$outputfile = "Output.csv"

$files = Get-ChildItem "*.csv"

#Get header
Get-Content -Path $files[0].FullName -TotalCount 1 | Set-Content -Path $outputfile

$files | ForEach-Object {
    #Get text but skip header
    Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1
} | Add-Content -Path $outputfile
```

Comment: Collecting the entire data in a variable might become a problem, particularly with large files. I'd do `Get-Content ... -TotalCount 1 | Set-Content Output.csv` and `$files | ForEach-Object {...} | Add-Content Output.csv` instead.

Comment: True, answer updated. I've not yet worked with files big enough to get a problem, but by saving it one part at a time like you suggested, you would be safe. My attempt was more of a "proof of concept". In a real scenario I would probably also use `[System.IO.File]`. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `sort name` is optional depending on whether the merge should also reorder the contents (obviously, you can `sort` on a different parameter as well). Same stipulation as above - all .csv files in one directory.

`dir c:\directory_containing_your\*.csv | Import-Csv | sort name | Export-Csv -Path c:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation`

From the [ScriptingGuy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/31/use-powershell-to-append-csv-files-easily.aspx).

Comment: The op is asking about multiple files. Not just one

Comment: @Matt this command accepts * input a la `c:\*.csv` and can address multiple files.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The op might not be. Since the question was specifically asking about multiple files the answer should address multiple files as well.

Comment: I get this error when I use above solution Import-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.

Comment: I guess this work-around makes it better. Get-ChildItem -filter *.csv | Select -expandProperty Name | Import-Csv

Answer (score 1):

Here's a heavily-commented solution that uses VBA in Excel to combine the CSVs. The strategy here is this:

1. Set your references up-front, most importantly the `strDir` variable (which is a string representing the directory that holds all your CSVs)
2. Loop through the directory
3. Open each CSV
4. Copy the appropriate contents from each CSV
5. Paste the contents to the output workbook
6. Repeat the loop until all files have been iterated over

Hope this helps!

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CombineCSVsInFolder()

Dim strFile As String, strDir As String
Dim wbkSource As Workbook, wbkOutput As Workbook
Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksOutput As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRowSource As Long, lngLastRowOutput As Long
Dim rngSource As Range, rngOutput As Range
Dim blnFirst As Boolean

'Set references up-front
strDir = "c:\stack\my_csvs\" '<~ edit this line with the CSV directory
strFile = Dir(strDir)
blnFirst = True
Set wbkOutput = Workbooks.Add
Set wksOutput = wbkOutput.ActiveSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through the CSV directory
While (strFile <> "")

    'Assign source CSV files
    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
    Set wksSource = wbkSource.ActiveSheet

    'Assign boundaries of area to copy and output
    lngLastRowSource = LastRowNum(wksSource)
    lngLastRowOutput = LastRowNum(wksOutput)
    With wksOutput
        Set rngOutput = .Cells(lngLastRowOutput + 1, 1)
    End With

    'If this is the first time through, include headers, otherwise do not
    If blnFirst = False Then
        With wksSource
            Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngLastRowSource, 4))
        End With
    'Special case for first iteration to correct source and output ranges
    Else
        With wksSource
            Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRowSource, 4))
        End With
        With wksOutput
            Set rngOutput = .Cells(1, 1)
        End With
        blnFirst = False
    End If


    'Execute copy, close source and repeat
    rngSource.Copy rngOutput
    wbkSource.Close
    strFile = Dir
Wend

'Turn screen updates back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRowNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        LastRowNum = 1
    End If
End Function
```